# Every time I open Live Server, the open tab in the browser always displays the icon of a project I've finished

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, visual-studio-extensions, liveserver

Every time I open Live Server, the open tab in the browser always displays the icon of a project I've finished, regardless of whether I've referenced a new icon or not.

Detail, the projects are in different repositories, always.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: does your latest project have an `favicon.ico`? The favicon gets cached by the browser.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @MaartenDev, that was this bro. Tnks!!! I didn't know it happened with the live server